# Enable error log on Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Is it possible to enable the error log for failed logins on cloud SQL (i.e. log_warnings = 2 ). I'm seeing a very large number of aborted connections / failed attempts and I want to be able to see what's causing this.

Answer (score 1):

Currently that's not possible because the mysql error log is not exposed. :-(

Comment: Still not possible? Stackdriver seems to access some of the MySQL log, but it doesn't work for anything else than instance startup/shutdown for me, at least.

Comment: OK, I've figured out that using MySQL 5.7 it works. I was using MySQL 5.6 and it didn't work for me.